# svmono+amsmath causes a warning

Tags: amsmath, sv-classes

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

generates the warning

```
Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine math accent \vec.
```

Is there any way to remove this warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `svmono` class by default redefines the `\vec` command, so `amsmath` emits its warning, because it finds a different definition than expected.

Just call

```
\documentclass[vecarrow]{svmono}
```

If you prefer to have the `svmono` default definition, do

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
```

while if you prefer the "italic bold" one that conforms to ISO regulations, do

```
\usepackage{bm}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}
```

In both cases this should go after having loaded `amsmath`. Both are more efficient than the clumsy definitions in `svmono.cls`.